# Mimic Immutability by Generating Data Structures of the Same/Similar Shape (not the Same Type)

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, immutability

Lately I frequently end up with different data structures of the same shape just to avoid altering the existing ones, so in order to mimic immutability. To make it easier to distinguish the layers of nested data structures and to keep them consistent with each other I wrap them in types that merely serve as "semantic wrappers". Here is the simplified pattern:

```js
const ListX = xs =>
  ({runListX: xs, [Symbol.toStringTag]: "ListX"});

const ListY = xs =>
  ({runListY: xs, [Symbol.toStringTag]: "ListY"});

const foo = [ListX([ListY([1, 2, 3]), ListY([4, 5, 6])])];

// later I gather more data that is related to foo but instead of
// altering foo I just create a new data structure

const bar = [ListX([ListY(["a", "b", "c"]), ListY(["d", "e", "f"])])];

const fold = f => init => xs =>
  xs.reduce((acc, x, i) => f(acc) (x, i), init);

const combining = foo => bar =>
  fold(acc1 => (tx, i) =>
    fold(acc2 => (ty, j) =>
      fold(acc3 => (x, k) => {
        const y = bar[i].runListX[j].runListY[k];
        return (acc3.push(x + y), acc3)
      }) (acc2) (ty.runListY)) (acc1) (tx.runListX)) ([]) (foo);

console.log(
  combining(foo) (bar)); // ["1a","2b","3c","4d","5e","6f"]
```

It works for me for programs with, say, 1000 lines of code. However, I wonder if it would still work for a larger code base. What are the long term drawbacks of this approach (maybe compared to real immutability gained by libs like immutable.js)? Has this approach/pattern even a name?

Please note that I am aware that this kind of question is probably too broad for SO. Still, it's all over my head.

Comment: I don't see the benefit of having `ListX` and `ListY` seperated here ...

Comment: The former could be a list of docs and the latter a list of records in each of them. In a real project the nesting would get way more deep, as complexity increases.

Comment: Why not `List("x")` then? Or `{ x: [...], y: null }` ?

Comment: What exactly are you afraid of? Why would you expect it to no longer work?

Comment: Your `combining` function is quite weird. I think you should implement it in terms of `zip` and `flatten`.

Comment: @Bergi: Don't get stuck with the contreived example. It's not just about nested arrays but object trees containing arrays. One drawback is that once the underlying shape changes I need to change all related data structures. But mostly I am afraid that these fragmented data structures impede the readability of my code when the code base growths. Is it worth this extra indirection?

Comment: In effect you are creating your own library for functional programming in JavaScript. If readability of your code by others is a major concern, this is definitely a problem since it will take whoever is reading it a fair amount of time simply to wrap their mind around your way of doing things. Furthermore, JavaScript isn't the fastest language. There must be some performance hit in the constant wrapping and unwrapping of data. This doesn't really answer your question, which is perhaps too opinion-based to answer.

Comment: @bob What do you mean by "underlying shape", those `ListX` and `ListY` wrappers? They should not change, yes. Or at least, not change their API - their constructors, and their methods like `fold`, `zip` or `flatten`, will need to work the same regardless of the implementation. And yes, directly accessing details like `runListX` inside a function like `combine` is a problem.

Comment: @Bergi I mean when during the development process `[ListX([ListY([a]), ListY([a])])]` becomes `[ListX([{foo: ListY([a]), ...}, {foo: ListY([a]), ...}])]`, then I'd have to adapt all related data structures.

Comment: @bob That's just what is called "development process" - making changes to code and data structures - and has nothing to do with whether you use `ListX` or not.

Comment: @Bergi No, because usually you have to change only a single data structure that contains all properties gathered during the program runs and not two or more data structures that each contain only a subset of properties and must be combined to get the overall picture.

Comment: @bob I have no idea what you are talking about. In the example, you changed `Array<ListX<ListY<A>>>` to `Array<ListX<Foo<ListY<A>>>>`, and of course you'll have to change all the code that uses this object. What "related data structures" do you mean?

Comment: @Bergi I feel like wasting your time. Another shot: Yes, but now I have to adapt `foo` and `bar` and each expression that relies on the shape of either `foo` or `bar`. Usually, I would store all related data just within `foo` instead of separating it. However, I don't have all data upfront, but get it step by step while the programming is running. Hence I had to mutate `foo` by adding the additional data, which is exactly what I am trying to avoid in the first place...